# Generate time between events giving wrong info

Tags: php, mysql, math, time

**The Issue**

In our calendar users can make events that will load into a MySQL database. The start time is stored and the end time is stored. In the database they are stored like this

```
start_time_first, start_time_second, end_time

example:
`9`, `30`, `11:00`     (9:30 - 11:00)
`13`, `10`, `14:25`    (1:10 - 2:25)
```

I then split the variables up when loaded to give me 4 variables which all works like expected using the following:

```
$real_time_start = $time_start[0] . $time_start[1]; // gives something like 930
$real_time_end = $time_end[0] . $time_end[1];       // gives something like 1100
$difference = $real_time_end - $real_time_start;    // find the difference
                                                    // pad the difference for 30 minutes
                                                    // and then format it for display
$difference = str_pad($difference, 3, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
$difference = $difference[0].":".substr($difference, -2, 2);
```

The obvious issue I am having is that if the `time_end` event is `1100` and the start is `930` that when I subtract them the value I get is 70 instead of 30. If the `time_end[1]` is lower than the `time_start[1]` then it will give me a bad value that doesn't work for time.

Here is a visual representation. As you can see the one value is correct while the other... not so much:

[image]

Is there a better way to simulate time between the two events in the way I am doing it or a better math I am missing to fix this issue? I had a go at writing a long way around it but it's much more difficult to get every occurrence the way I had written it. Hopefully this can help someone else in the future as well.

**The database structure**

[image]

Comment: Why not use the database datetime field type? Then you can use built in php date functions to work out differences which will take in to account the number of hours in the day correctly

Comment: Or even do the DIFF calc in MYSQL as well.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using MySQL's built-in date/datetime/time  functions? You're making this much harder on yourself and require more functions than what's really needed. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: Who on earth decided to store the times like that. Shoot them

Comment: That's not how the information is being stored and there is a good 5000 entry's already from the past years with this company. I am simply trying to figure out how long the job lasted using their old archive without converting everything.Its not necessary, but it's a neat feature they asked for.

Comment: Something that's naturally base 60 is being calculated using base 100 so yeah, it's going to go squiffy... from where you're at, your best bet might be `DateTime::sub` or similar : http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.sub.php

Comment: So show us the schema for that table. If the data is stored sensibly then its an easy job to do it in either MYSQL or PHP

Comment: It does not want to be humanly readable if you want to calculate differences, it needs to be machine readable i.e. a DateTime or probably better still a TIMESTAMP

Comment: @CD001 I was looking at converting it using `strtotime` but there is no seconds field saved on the database.

Comment: Please show us how it is really stored on the database. Anything is possible but only if we know exactly what we are dealing with

Comment: Added the database structure to the OP

Comment: W'D'F is that when its at home with its boots off. Good luck with this...... you are gona need it

Comment: If you're really got 3 columns like `9`, `30` and `11:30` in the database, then with a bit of string concatenation you could still do something like `$start = DateTime::createFromFormat('g:h', "{$time_start[0]}:{$time_start[1]}");` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the decimal system to subtract day times because minutes flow from 60 to the next hour and not from 100. PHP provides the DateTime/DateInterval classes for this:

```
$start=new DateTime('9:30');
$end=new DateTime('11:00');
$diff=$start->diff($end);
var_dump($diff->format('%H:%i'));
```

(This is just to demonstrate; theoretically this can be problematic with DST, so if you can you should include the date as well to have an exact solution.)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why I didn't think of this before but thanks to some nice commenters I have added :00 to the end of the time and then `strtotime` them so I have the difference in seconds between events. From here it's easy to convert the seconds to a readable output of hours, minutes, and the like. Thanks everyone for their help!

```
$real_time_start = $time_start[0] .":". $time_start[1] .":00";
$real_time_end = $time_end[0] .":". $time_end[1] .":00";
$real_time_start = strtotime($day . "-" . $month . "-" . $year . " " . $real_time_start);
$real_time_end = strtotime($day . "-" . $month . "-" . $year . " " . $real_time_end);
$difference = $real_time_end - $real_time_start;
```